# Async await and fetch syntax not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Here is my code:

```
export class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    async fetchSport(sport) {
        let headers = new Headers()
        headers.append('key-goes-here', 'pass-goes-here')
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json')
        let request = new Request('api-url-goes-here' + sport, {headers: headers})
        let data = await fetch(request).then(response => response.json()).then(json => json.players.forward)
        console.log(data) // 'Christopher Brown'
        return data
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='app'>
                <SportPlayers
                    sport={this.fetchSport('soccer')}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
>   Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the
>   React add-ons. Check the render method of `SportPlayers`.

I am trying to figure out why this error is showing. The `fetchSport` function should be returning a string (like console.log suggests), but it seems like a promise is returned to the view instead.

Bellow is my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"],
    output: {
        path: "/dist/assets",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: "./dist",
        port: 3000 
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ["babel-loader", 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2016,presets[]=stage-3,presets[]=react'],
            },
            {
                test:  /\.json$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ["json-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call a `fetch` method from `render`. Also, `fetchSport` returns a promise, which you cannot pass to `SportPlayers`

Comment: Async functions *always* returns a promise; that's what async functions are for.

Comment: that's the danger of using async await, people often think they are writing synchronous code, in fact **async await** enables you to write `asynchronous` code the same way you would write synchronous code. Maybe you should start by learning how es6 generators works to fully understand the concept of async await

Comment: By the way the data you return at the end of your function would be reachable with this code `this.fetchSport('soccer').then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: @Bergi @Frxstrem @oliv37 Thanks all of you. I did not notice async functions always return a promise. So, can I still use `fetch` in this case? What is the correct context to invoke it. I am new to React.

Answer (score 5):

As many people have said already, an `async` function will always return a `Promise` object, whose value you can then obtain by using `.then()`.

In general, if you need to make many requests to a server, you should be using a state management framework such as [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). However, Redux introduces a lot of boilerplate. If your usecase is simple, you could just use [local UI state](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html) to store the result of your call.

Something like this:

```
export class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { sport: '' }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchSport('soccer').then(sport => this.setState({ sport }))
    }

    async fetchSport(sport) {
        let headers = new Headers()
        headers.append('key-goes-here', 'pass-goes-here')
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json')
        let request = new Request('api-url-goes-here' + sport, {headers: headers})
        let data = await fetch(request).then(response => response.json()).then(json => json.players.forward)
        console.log(data) // 'Christopher Brown'
        return data
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='app'>
                <SportPlayers
                    sport={this.state.sport}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```